# In ubuntu generate tomcat's catalina.out file seperate for each date

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, window

Previously I was using Windows server and in that, standard output log file generated by tomcat used to be different for each date, i.e., for 7 days in a week tomcat generated 7 different output files.

But now I migrated to ubuntu and now tomcat generates just a single standard output file with named **catalina.out** and all output contents keep on appending in it only. Which increases size of this file very much goes in several MBs which takes time to download if I want to see logs and also consumes my internet bandwidth plus I fail to figure out logs only for a particular date.

Is there any setting for this in tomcat? I am using tomcat 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatically archiving logs by time or size is a process referred to as log rotation. You can use the [log rotation in the OS](http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/6/30/understanding-logrotate-on-ubuntu-part-1) or you can [configure Tomcat to do so](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Logging#Q10). Either way, it looks like you're writing too much to stdout. You should consider logging using log4j or something similar.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I am planning to use log4j